# Save to host computer from server using VNC

Tags: automation, save, vnc, sikuli

In tightVNC, there is a transfer file dialogue that lets you manually move things between the remote and local systems. I would like to write a script that lets me perform actions on the remote computer and then in the end save directly to the local system (so I can then have the script pick up the file on the local system and proceed onward without user intervention). To do this, I would need some kind of logical address extension to put in the save as dialogue on the remote computer that will address it to the local computer, ie `StuffForConnection::C:\LocationOnLocalComputer\filename.txt` or something similar. Alternately, I would need a way to tell the server to send the file across once it was saved on that system.

I am using Sikuli to operate the remote system, as what I am running is a closed source GUI based piece of software, so I am entering directly into the save as box. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automated way to do this, short of running a separate FTP between the systems.